# I am trying to render data from mongodb server to react app. And it's not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, axios, mern

This is the console log error

```
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_id, inputText, __v}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
at throwOnInvalidObjectType (react-dom.development.js:14887:1)
at reconcileChildFibers (react-dom.development.js:15828:1)
at reconcileChildren (react-dom.development.js:19167:1)
at updateHostComponent (react-dom.development.js:19924:1)
at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21618:1)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
```

I am being able to save my input to the server but am getting error while trying to fetch it.
Here's the component which is supposed to return the list.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ToDoItem from "./ToDoItem";
import InputArea from "./InputArea";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import axios from "axios";

const ToDoList = () => {
const [x, setX] = useState([]);
const xList = () => {
return x.map((y,index) => {
  return <ToDoItem key={index} text={y} />;
});
};
useEffect(() => {
axios
  .get("http://localhost:5000/")
  .then((res) => {
    setX(res.data);
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);

 return (
 <div className="container">
  <div className="heading">
    <h1>To-Do List</h1>
  </div>
  <InputArea />
  <div>{xList()}</div>
 </div>
 );
 };

 export default ToDoList;
```

Comment: it happens when you try to render normal object instead of JSX element ( react node).
eg ```<div>{{ foo: 'bar' }}</div>```  will throw similar error . I think its because `ToDoItem` check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That specific error usually occurs when you are trying to print out an entire object instead of lets say the properties from each object.

Can you console.log the list and let us know what properties you have for each object?

Comment: Sounds like a good comment and not response ;p

Comment: Thank you. I was actually trying to return the whole object stored in the server. Hence, the error. I just needed to return the data that I want to be displayed. Thanks for the help